# What is the alternative to $q.all in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Q library and $q.all to make few calls. How to replicate the same with react?

Comment: You don't need a promise library any more (most of the time); it's baked in, use Promise.all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually talking about the Q library, then Q.allSettled() is precisely for this purpose:

```
Q.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).then(function (results) {
// results is an array of objects of the form:
//  { state: "fulfilled", value: ... }
// or
//  { state: "rejected", reason: ... }
});
```

If you're talking about the $q included in AngularJS, it doesn't have this method, but 
  you could make your own ad-hoc version:

```
myApp.service('allSettled', ['$q', function ($q) {
return function (values) {
    return $q.all(values.map(function (value) {
        return $q.resolve(value)
            .then(function (result) {
                 return { state: "fulfilled", value: result };
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                 return { state: "rejected", reason: error };
            });
       }));
    }
}])
```